# Can I use nerdctl and build image with buildkit in a sidecar container

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit, nerdctl, buildkit

I have a Jenkins pod with `nerdctl` binary in the main container. This pod has a `buildkit` sidecar container. Can I use `nerdctl build` command using this sidecar container as the builder?
Right now I'm using `buildctl` and connect to that `buildkit` container using `--addr` but I want to use `nerdctl` as well since it has more options like running container images and copying file from a container to the local filesystem.